# Cómo validar varios input tipo text

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Buenas noches a todos, quisiera pedirle su ayuda con un formulario que tengo que validar pero tengo varios campos que necesitan ser validados mi pregunta es habrá alguna manera de hacerlo por Javascript sin necesidad de declarar una variable por cada campo de mi formación?
De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

En este link esta el codigo

https://codepen.io/nabux/pen/xpOaGd

Comment: Puedes asociar una función "validar" al evento `change` de cada campo. Así, esa función sólo tendrá que validar el valor de `this`. Puedes asociar dos funciones distintas, "validarUsuario" y "validarContra" (p.ej.) a los campos según su `type` si quieres validaciones por tipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías separar las funciones `validateForm` y la validación de password.
Primero deberías cambiar el id y nombre de los campos select que contiene Si/No y de los campos input que contienen el password de la siguiente forma:

```
Cuenta usuario 1: select Si/no -> sel_psw1; input: txt_psw1
Cuenta usuario 2: select Si/no -> sel_psw2; input: txt_psw2
Cuenta usuario N: select Si/no -> sel_pswN; input: txt_pswN
```

Función que valida el formulario:

```
function validarForm() {
    var sel_psw, txt_psw;
    var s_errores = "";

    for (var num_cuenta_usuario = 1; num_cuenta_usuario < 6; num_cuenta_usuario ++) {
        var sel_psw = document.getElementById("sel_psw" + num_cuenta_usuario);
        var txt_psw = document.getElementById("txt_psw" + num_cuenta_usuario);
        if (validarPassword(sel_psw.value, txt_psw.value) === false) {
            s_errores += "Cuenta de usuario " + num_cuenta_usuario + ": por favor digitar la contraseña\n";
        }
    }

    if (s_errores.length > 0) {
        alert(s_errores);
    }
}
```

Función que valida el password:

```
function validarPassword(sel_psw_value, txt_psw_value) {
    if(sel_psw_value=="si" && !txt_psw_value){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Función que habilita el campo de password:

```
function activarPassword(sel_txt, txt_psw) {
    if(sel_txt.value == "si") {
        txt_psw.disabled = false;
        txt_psw.focus();
    } else {
        txt_psw.value = "";
        txt_psw.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Función evento `onchange` del `select`:

```
function sel_psw_onchange() {
    //this = sel_pswX
    var num_cuenta_usuario = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
    var txt_psw = document.getElementById("txt_psw" + num_cuenta_usuario);
    activarPassword(this, txt_psw);
}
```

Función evento `onblur`del `input.text`:

```
function txt_psw_onblur() {
    //this = txt_pswX
    var num_cuenta_usuario = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
    var sel_psw = document.getElementById("sel_psw" + num_cuenta_usuario);

    if (validarPassword(sel_psw.value, this.value) === false) {
        alert("Por favor digitar la contraseña");
        this.focus();
    }
}
```

Una vez cargada la página estableces los eventos de la siguiente manera:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var num_cuenta_usuario = 1; num_cuenta_usuario < 6; num_cuenta_usuario ++) {
        var sel_psw = document.getElementById("sel_psw" + num_cuenta_usuario);
        var txt_psw = document.getElementById("txt_psw" + num_cuenta_usuario);

        sel_psw.onchange = sel_psw_onchange;

        txt_psw.onblur = txt_psw_onblur;
    }

    var btn_enviar = document.getElementById("btn_Enviar");
    btn_enviar.onclick = validarForm;
}
```

Es muy fácil aumentar/disminuir el número de cuentas de usuario si lo necesitas en un futuro sin variar apenas el código, simplemente cambiando el límite superior del bucle `for` (podrías crear una variable que contenga ese número y así no has de buscar en el código todos los bucles para cambiar el valor).

El código está sin probar, pero esto te puede dar una idea de cómo hacerlo.